# Why can't I extend docker postgres image to create extra database and user

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm using [docker postgres 9.4.5](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/postgres/) images and extendeding it using an init.sh copied to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` in the docker container. I am trying to create another database and a non admin user that as access to both `$POSTGRES_DB` as well as the 2nd database I am creating.
I tried the following where `$POSTGRES_USER` is the user `myadmin` and `$POSTGRES_DB` is the database `mydb1` passed through docker-compose environment:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" <<-EOSQL
   CREATE USER userx WITH password '$POSTGRES_PASSWORD';
   CREATE DATABASE diagnostics;
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE userx TO $POSTGRES_DB;
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE userx TO mydb2;
EOSQL
```

This gave me an error:

```
postgres_1   | CREATE DATABASE
postgres_1   | 
postgres_1   | CREATE ROLE
postgres_1   | 
postgres_1   | 
postgres_1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-user-db.sh
postgres_1   | FATAL:  database "myadmin" does not exist
postgres_1   | psql: FATAL:  database "myadmin" does not exist
docker_postgres_1 exited with code 2
```

I then tried it with `--username postgres` and now get the error

```
ERROR:  database "userx" does not exist
```

I then tried to create the database userx:
    #!/bin/bash
    set -e

```
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" <<-EOSQL
   CREATE DATABASE userx;       
   CREATE USER userx WITH password '$POSTGRES_PASSWORD';
   CREATE DATABASE diagnostics;
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE userx TO $POSTGRES_DB;
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE userx TO mydb2;
EOSQL
```

but got:

```
postgres_1   | CREATE DATABASE
postgres_1   | ERROR:  role "mydb1" does not exist
postgres_1   | STATEMENT:  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE rwx TO analytics;
postgres_1   | ERROR:  role "mydb2" does not exist
docker_postgres_1 exited with code 3
```

Can someone please help, this is a real blocker for me and I have no idea how to proceed as I feel that I should not need to be creating the database userx or the roles , or am I wrong?

Comment: i think your GRANT is not correct... it's GRANT ALL  PRIVILEGES ON *yourdbname not user* TO *your user*

Comment: @user3012759 Thank you soo much, sill school boy error on my part. If you want to add this as an answer I will happily accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GRANT syntax was not quite right - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-grant.html

In short should be like that:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON yourdbname not user TO your user;
```